# How to parse user intent and put part of it into a variable with Dialogflow (api.ai)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

When creating a dialogflow agent, I would like to parse a user input like "set the alarm at 6AM" into "set alarm" intent and 6AM as a variable, essentially in the same sentence, not a conversation like "set the alarm" then "6AM", is there a way to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as your training phrase, use something like "set the alarm at 6am".

You'll see that Dialogflow detects "6AM" as a valid time and automatically creates a parameter for it.

[image]